# Solve the differential equation: $\frac{d}{dx}(2y y') = (y')^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am solving the following problem:
$$\frac{d}{dx}(2y y') = (y')^2$$
with $y(0) = y(1) = 0$.

The above equation is the same as:
$$y'/y = -2 y''/y'$$
$$\implies y - C = (y')^{-2}$$
This form is unfamiliar to me. Can you give some help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $z=y-C$. The equation is now $z=(z')^{-2}$, or $z'=z^{-\frac12}$. You should be able to solve this, and substitute back what $y$ was.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is equivalent with $2y'^2+2yy''=y'^2$ or with $y'^2+2yy''=0$. Use substitution $y'=z$, where $z=z(y)$, $z'=y''=z'z$. Your equation is then $z^2+2yzz'=0$, from where we get $z=0$ or $z+2yz'=0$. From first equation we get $y'=0$ and $y=C$ and second equation is linear ODE $z'+\frac{z}{2y}=0$, which is equivalent with $(\sqrt{y}z)'=0$ or $z=\frac{C}{\sqrt{y}}$. By returning substitution, we get $\sqrt{y}dy=Cdx$ or $\frac{2}{3}y^{\frac{3}{2}}=Cx+D$ and $y=(\frac{3}{2}(Cx+D))^\frac{2}{3}$. Since $y(0)=y(1)=0$, we get $D=0$ and $C+D=0$, from where we get solution $y=0$.

Answer (score 0):

From

$$y'/y = -2 y''/y'\to \ln y + 2\ln y'=C_0\to \ln(y y'^2)=C_0\to y y'^2= C_1\to y'\sqrt{y} = \pm C_2$$

which is separable.